# How to give full path name for a file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to give the full path for a file "Sample.xml" in ASP.NET in the following code

```
Response.Redirect("Sample.xml");
```

It does not work if I try like "C:\Users\abc\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\Sample.xml"

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/Sample.xml"));
```

I am assuming Sample.xml is in the root of your website.

Comment: @PriyamChandra - What happens?

Comment: Thanks , it does work, I was somewhere wrong in syntax.